# Simple Xpath finding specific information

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to find which actor played Simba on "The lion King".I do know if i type
`//Disney/Subsidiaries/Subsidiary/Movie[Cast/Role[contains(@Name,'Simba')]]/Name` I get the movie's name, but i want to retrieve the actor's name who's played Simba.

```
    <Movie>
    <Name lang="en">The Lion King</Name>
    <Year>2019</Year>
    <ScreenTime unit="minutes">118</ScreenTime>
    <Cast>
      <Role name="Simba" actor="DonaldGlover" />
      <Role name="Mufasa" actor="JamesEarlJones" />
      <Role name="Nala" actor="BeyoncéKnowles" />
      <Role name="Timon" actor="BillyEichner" />
      <Role name="Pumbaa" actor="SethRogen" />
    </Cast>
  </Movie>
```

I've tried 
//Disney/Subsidiaries/Subsidiary/Movie[Cast/Role[contains(@actor,'Simba')]]/actor

in this case, i expect it to return.
 "DonaldGlove"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
 //Movie/Cast/Role[@name='Simba']/@actor
```

It outputs:

> DonaldGlover